# How can I tell if picam is working with ROS2 Humble?

Tags: ros-humble, raspberry-pi

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 on a rpi4(2gb) from Raspberry Pi's images.
I have installed libcamera from Raspberry Pi github and built rpicam-apps from source.

Now, my problem is how to know if it has worked.  My main pc still runs Ubuntu 20.04/Noetic, so it can't talk to Humble on the rpi4.  What is the simplest way to see if ROS2 can send video to a topic?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

Install camera_ros from
https://github.com/christianrauch/camera_ros/tree/main

Run the node:

```
ros2 run camera_ros camera_node --ros-args -p width:=640 -p height:=480
```

Use topic to check that video is being published:

```
ros2 topic hz /camera/image_raw
```

This is a round about route to showing the camera is working, but the usual tools like guvcview don't seem to work with libcamera, and the rpicam tools don't either.